# How to add and access key value pairs from appsettings.config file in visual studio code?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, app-config

I have written my C# logic in a console application using the .net core and sdk on visual studio code. I'm trying to add a config file to configure certain parameters, however, once I create the appsettings.json file, I'm unable to access it in the code. Need help to access the values from config file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        var appSettings = new Config();
           var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddEnvironmentVariables() //This line doesnt compile 
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
             .Build();
           config.Bind(appSettings);       //This line doesnt compile        

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine($" Hello {appSettings.name} !"); 
        }
    }
    public class Config
    {
       public string name{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `appsettings.json`

Comment: {
    "name" : "Gary"
}

Answer (score 2):

HomeController.cs

```
    public class HomeController : Controller {

       private readonly IConfiguration _config;

       public HomeController(IConfiguration config) { _config = config; }

       public IActionResult Index() {

          Console.WriteLine(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value);

          return View();

           }
   }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Token": "T21pZC1NaXJ6YWVpWhithOutStar*"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace testapp
{
    class Program
    {            
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var appSettings = new Config();
           var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
             .Build();
           config.Bind(appSettings); 

           Console.WriteLine($" Hello {appSettings.name} !");
        }
    }

    public class Config
    {
       public string name{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

> appsettings.json

```
{
    "name": "appName"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this, but the code doesn't compile as IConfigurationRoot doesn't contain the definition for Bind method.

Comment: use this `var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()` to create object of `ConfigurationBuilder`

Comment: I have done as suggested, but still, it doesn't compile. Are you able to compile it at your end?

Comment: using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        var appSettings = new Config();
           var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .Build();  
            config.Bind(appSettings);               

            Console.WriteLine($" Hello {config.name} !");
        }
    }
    public class Config
    {
       public string name{ get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: I have edited my answer,`basepath` and `AddEnvironmentVariables` were missing.you can try that now.

Comment: Still, I'm unable to compile it.

Comment: can you edit your question and post the updated code which you are using.

Comment: I have used the same code which you provided as you can see in the screenshot and it's working properly.
make sure you have update your `appsettings.json` like this -

`{
  "name": "sssssss"
}`

Comment: when I compile I get this error : "{
 "resource": "/e:/Rahul/Visual Studio/testapp/Program.cs",
 "owner": "csharp",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "'IConfigurationRoot' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no accessible extension method 'Bind' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationRoot' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) [testapp]",
 "startLineNumber": 17,
 "startColumn": 19,
 "endLineNumber": 17,
 "endColumn": 23
}"

Comment: I get error "The type or namespace Config could not be found." ROFL 2023 and still this is hard!